# iOS sharing code between a completion block and a method

Tags: ios, block

I have a completion block
(specifically `FBAppCallHandler callHandler = ^(FBAppCall *call)`)

I have a code I want to call from this block, but also call it from a different method in the class.

How do I share code between a block and a class method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method in the class for example `-(void)foo`.
Then you can call it anywhere in the class, include the block.

Please note not to call to self inside the block to avoid retain cycles. 
More info [here](http://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/).

Comment: I'm getting Use of undeclared identifier... (of foo). The block is: `FBAppCallHandler callHandler = ^(FBAppCall *call){
... };`

Comment: Did you declarer it on the `@interface` ?

Comment: Well I made it a + method in AppDelegate and called it using [AppDelegate foo] - but yes - I should have declared it, you are totally right... 10X